# Jekyll: 'About' permalink not working properly

Tags: configuration, jekyll, github-pages, permalinks

I'm configuring a *Jekyll* website with the [Lanyon](https://github.com/poole/lanyon) theme but the configuration on the **site url,baseurl and permalinks** is so unclear to me.

Thus my `_config.yml` uses:

```
url: "https://edgeoftech.github.io/"
baseurl: /blog
permalink: pretty
```

And my `about.md` page uses:

```
permalink: /about
```

When the site is served, main page is served at `http://127.0.0.1:4000/blog/` and about page at `http://127.0.0.1:4000/blog/about`, but **the ABOUT link on the website takes me to `http://127.0.0.1:4000/about`**.

How can I configure both the link and the 'about' page to be linked to the same url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found your question as I was actively searching for the answer myself. I've just sorted it out with the Hyde theme, which is closely related. My `_config.yml` file looks very similar:

```
url:                 https://annedorko.github.io/
baseurl:             "/intp/"
permalink:           pretty
```

The trick is actually in the hard-coded URLs. There are two primary places to fix this. The first is in the `sidebar.html` – be sure to add the `site.baseurl` in front of the `node.url`.

```
<a class="sidebar-nav-item{% if page.url == node.url %} active{% endif %}" href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ node.url }}">{{ node.title }}</a>
```

You'll also need to edit all the relative links in `head.html`, similar to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}public/css/poole.css">
```

Finally, be sure to add the updated post links on `index.html`:

```
<a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">
   {{ post.title }}
</a>
```

This may not cover all of your scenarios as the themes are a bit different (though still based off of Poole), but should get you started in the right direction. Best of luck!

Comment: **The trick is actually in the hard-coded URLs**. Thanks a lot @AnneDorko !

Comment: It is important to note that the `permalink: pretty` line should not be nested.